# Should I create a shell alias or a shell function to use this grep synthax easier?

Tags: shell

I often search with grep in markdown documents. I search for lines that start with # (first-level titles).

```
grep -in '^#\s.*WORDIMLOOKINGFOR.*$' *.md
```

I want to use a simple shell command like:

```
$ f# WORD IM LOOKING FOR
```

Use f# (find #) shortening and supply the search term as an argument or something. Or f# then press TAB and show the whole grep line positioning the cursor on the WORDIMLOOKINGFOR. Is it possible to do that in shell?

Comment: You should create a function.  Aliases have been effectively deprecated for decades.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. That helped me a lot.

Comment: Using `#` in a name makes your code a lot less portable -- not just incompatible with other shells, but also potentially to future versions of bash. If such names stopped being supported in the future, it wouldn't be the first time undefined behavior that happened to work but wasn't _documented_ to work got cleaned up -- look at the changes around environment variables with bad names that happened in the revisions following publication of the shellshock vulnerability.

Comment: BTW, if you're on a GNU system, consider using the `-P` argument to `grep` to ensure that `\s` will work. Without `-P` (which explicitly requests PCRE extensions), the only way to say "match a space of any kind" that's strictly guaranteed to work is `[[:space:]]`. Or, for better portability, you can use `'^#[[:space:]]*'"$1"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.*$` in the pattern is pretty pointless, so I've omitted that, but you can just do:

```
f_() { grep -in '^#.*'"$1" *.md; }
```

Perhaps you want to use "$@", but it's not really clear to me how you intend to use the function.  Don't use aliases.  As stated in the bash man page circa 1996, "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."  I'm fairly certain the "almost every purpose" is just the author covering against unseen cases that probably do not exist anymore.  Consider aliases totally deprecated.  They have no place in the modern world.

Comment: ...though using `#` in a name is depending on undefined behavior, being outside the set of names that [POSIX guarantees to work](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235) (which use only "underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set", and do not start with a digit).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy makes an excellent point.   And, stylistically, using `#` in a name is nearly as abhorrent as using `::`.    I can't imagine any competent organization trying to pretend their shell functions live in a namespace by using `::` with a prefix!